# How to merge two tables using SAS proc sql

Tags: sql, sas, proc

Here is the exam data table that I would like to process here:

-origin data

--a table

| STU_ID | STU_KEY | STU_CODE_1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2002123 | A121 |
| 124 | 2002124 | A122 |
| 125 | 2002125 | A123 |
| 126 | 2002126 | A124 |

--b table
|STU_ID|STU_KEY|STU_CODE_2|
|------|-------|----------|
|123   |2002223|B121      |
|124   |2002224|B122      |
|125   |2002225|C123      |
|126   |2002226|C124      |
|127   |2002127|C125      |

I want to merge between 'a' and 'b' tables using code of SAS proc sql as follows.

-result data merge table

| STU_ID | STU_KEY | STU_CODE_1 | STU_CODE_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2002123 | A121 |  |
| 123 | 2002223 |  | B121 |
| 124 | 2002124 | A122 |  |
| 124 | 2002224 |  | B122 |
| 125 | 2002125 | A123 |  |
| 125 | 2002225 |  | C123 |
| 126 | 2002126 | A124 |  |
| 126 | 2002226 |  | C124 |
| 127 | 2002127 |  | C125 |

```
 '''error code'''
 PROC SQL;
 CREATE TABLE a_b_merge as
 SELECT t1.STU_ID, 
        t1.STU_KEY, 
        t1.STU_CODE_1
        t2.STU_CODE_2
 FROM a as t1 full join b as t2
 ON t1.STU_ID=t2.STU_ID
 QUIT;
```

Let me know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several syntax errors in your query:

- A missing `,` after `t1.STU_CODE_1`
- A missing `;` before the `quit;`

In order to get the expected result, use `OUTER UNION CORR`. `OUTER UNION` keep all rows and all columns from the two intermediate result sets and `CORR` causes PROC SQL to match the columns in table-expressions by name. Also add an `ORDER BY` to match the expected output.

```
data table_a;
infile datalines4 delimiter="|";
input stu_id stu_key stu_code_1 :$8.;
datalines4;
123|2002123|A121
124|2002124|A122
125|2002125|A123
126|2002126|A124
;;;;

data table_b;
    infile datalines4 delimiter="|";
    input stu_id stu_key stu_code_2 :$8.;
    datalines4;
123|2002223|B121
124|2002224|B122
125|2002225|C123
126|2002226|C124
127|2002227|C125
;;;;

proc sql;
    create table want as
    select * from table_a 
    outer union corr
    select * from table_b
    order by stu_id, stu_key;
quit;
```

[image]